# How to create HashMap with streams overriding duplicates?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm creating a `HashMap` using java8 `stream` API as follows:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = dao.findAll().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getType, Entity::getValue));
```

Now if an element is added to the collection where the key already exists, I just want to keep the existing element in the list and skip

the additional element. How can I achieve this? Probably I have to make use of `BinaryOperation<U>` of `toMap()`, but could anyone provide

an example of my specific case?

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation? Because they provide an example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need that `BinaryOperation<U>` and use it as a third argument for `Collectors.toMap()`.

In case of a conflict (appearance of an already existing key) you get to choose between value `oldValue` (the existing one) and `newValue`. In the code example we always take value `oldValue`. But you are free to do anything else with these two values (take the larger one, merge the two etc.).

The following example shows one possible solution where the existing value always remains in the map:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = dao.findAll().stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getType, Entity::getValue, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue));
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator) for another example.